# random choice with seed in python

Tags: python, random

I have two lists a and b with same length as below

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [11,22,33,44,55]
```

How can i choose elements in a using random.choices such that exact corresponding items in b are also picked.

Both a and b will always be of same length. and both the elements of a and b are related based on index. so, in short, what i am trying to do is randomly select an element in a and then be able to pick the corresponding  element in b. One thing is that the elements might be repeated.

Comment: You can't put the elements into *one* list with tuples or 2-element lists?

Comment: i can, but the problem is the number of elements in a and b are in millions

Comment: is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you should really be using a different storage altogether. Like a numpy array perhaps.

Comment: okay, if its numpy, is there any solution for this?

Comment: i was thinking of spark rdd's too. Do you think i should just make an rdd and then sample it out?

Comment: If `A` is a multidimensional numpy array and numpy is imported as `np`, then `A[np.random.randint(A.shape[0])]`  gives you a random row in that array.

Comment: I have no experience with spark RDD's, sorry.

Comment: i think i will first just get np.random.randint(A.shape[0]) into a variable and then index both A and B with the same indexes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176028/discussion-between-inaflash-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better option would be to put your lists into one list:

```
a_b = list(zip(a, b))
```

then pick from that with `random.choice()`.

Failing that, use [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) to pick an index at random:

```
ridx = random.randrange(len(a))
aval, bval = a[ridx], b[ridx]
```

The implementation for `random.choice()` uses the exact same codepath to pick a random index as what `randrange()` with a single argument uses to determine a random integer within the range.